# Sending Data From background.js to extension.js in crossrider

Tags: javascript, browser-extension, crossrider

I am developing a browser extension using crossrider.
I have added a context menu (background.js)

```
   var ContextData;
    appAPI.contextMenu.add("key1", "Send Data To Server", function (data) {
        var ContextData = 'pageUrl: ' + data.pageUrl + '\r\n' +
                         'linkUrl: ' + data.linkUrl + '\r\n' +
                         'selectedText:' + data.selectedText + '\r\n' +
                         'srcUrl:' + data.srcUrl;

    }, ["all"]);
```

On user click I want to send `ContextData` to `extension.js.` At extension.js some function will receive the data and send it to my server (A Rest API which will accept the data).

To send data to the server I have tested this and it works fine (code sample in extension.js)

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {

var dataToSend =="test data";

    appAPI.request.post({
        url: 'REST API URL',
        postData: dataToSend,
        onSuccess: function(response, additionalInfo) {
            var details = {};

            details.response = response;

        },
        onFailure: function(httpCode) {
        //  alert('POST:: Request failed. HTTP Code: ' + httpCode);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I write a function to accept `ContextData` from `background.js` and assign it to dataToSend in extension.js?

Comment: See http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message

Comment: yes I have read this link but there is no any method for communication between backgrond.js and extension.js. By mot of the methods we can send messages to current tabs or all tabs,etc. But that is not my requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Neel If I understand your requirements correctly, @Rob is essentially correct though a little clarification may help

By design/architecture, the *extension.js* code runs on each HTML page i.e. a separate *extension.js* instance is run for each URL that loads. In contrast, the context menu runs at the browser level (not HTML page) and is hence correctly coded in *background.js* file. However, the *background.js* code does not have direct access to the *extension.js* instance code running on the HTML page in the active tab and must therefore [communicate the data via messaging](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message). (For more information about scopes, see [Scopes Overview](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/scopes))

Obviously, a user clicks the context menu item on the active tab (i.e. the page showing the HTML page being viewed); hence, once the **ContextData** string is created, you can use [appAPI.message.toActiveTab](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message-method-toActiveTab) to send the string to the *extension.js* instance running on the page/tab where the the context menu item was clicked.

This being the case, using your code example you can achieve this goal as follows:

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  var ContextData;
  appAPI.contextMenu.add("key1", "Send Data To Server", function (data) {
    var ContextData = 'pageUrl: ' + data.pageUrl + '\r\n' +
      'linkUrl: ' + data.linkUrl + '\r\n' +
      'selectedText:' + data.selectedText + '\r\n' +
      'srcUrl:' + data.srcUrl;
    appAPI.message.toActiveTab({type:'dataToSend', data: ContextData});
  }, ["all"]);
});
```

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  var dataToSend =="test data";

  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'dataToSend') {
      appAPI.request.post({
        url: 'REST API URL',
        postData: dataToSend,
        onSuccess: function(response, additionalInfo) {
            var details = {};
            details.response = response;
        },
        onFailure: function(httpCode) {
          //  alert('POST:: Request failed. HTTP Code: ' + httpCode);
        }
      });   
    }
  });
});
```

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was missing the point that extension.js code runs on each HTML page i.e. a separate extension.js instance is run for each URL that loads. Thanks for clearification :)

Comment: Pleasure. BTW, unless you have a specific need to send the data to the extension.js scope, you can actually just post the data directly from the background.js scope ;-)

Comment: This is great! I think it should be included in the demo linked from the [docs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.contextMenu).