# How can you tell which element was selected with a crossrider contextMenu

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, crossrider

The data returned by the callback for `appAPI.contextMenu` is currently only the following:

- pageUrl
- linkUrl
- selectedText
- srcUrl

There doesn't seem like there's a way to tell what was actualy right clicked on, only a little information about it. I could for example search all images and find the one with the matching `srcUrl`, but what if the same image appears multiple times?

I could try catching right click events in `extension.js` and try to match them with context menu events, but this seems quite round about.

What's the expected method to find the selected element (after [receiving the event in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740482/sending-data-from-background-js-to-extension-js-in-crossrider))?

Lets say for example I want to be able to right click an image and `display:none` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Crossrider platform does not support the feature you require and I think your workaround is reasonable. However, I have forwarded your suggestion to the Crossrider development team, who will consider it for future releases.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Any status on this? Would be a useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, this actually seems quite reliable although I haven't tested much. TBH I was expecting coherency issues:

```
//in extension.js (background.js just forward context menu events)
var lastRightClicked = null;
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { //I guess a mousedown event would work here too
    lastRightClicked = e.target;
}, true);

appAPI.message.addListener({channel:"contextmenu"}, function(message) {
    if (message.menuitem == "Hide")
        lastRightClicked.style.display = "none";
});
```